# How to recover corrupted excel file

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver

Im working in eclipse with selenium using excel sheet to give input and output.When Im doing my work suddenly I got my file corrupted and got this as error message   like this,

org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

and then I opened my file folder ,its just 0 KB and when I try to open its giving me the alert "excel will not open this file ,because file formatter file extension not valid.Verify that the file has not been corrupted and matches the file extensions matches the formate of file." I tried all the things which has been recommended by excel support.But its not.I cant buy a tool for this.Can anyone help me on this..

Comment: If it were just corrupted then you might have a chance, but since you say it's 0KB it sounds like the data is gone. If you don't have a backup and (likely) can't recover it from RAM then you're SOL. Sorry.

Comment: Ooh, don't get your hopes up too much, but try to see if you can recover the files from the caches of whatever browsers you're using.